# parsing html to get data

Tags: html-parsing

i am having a problem with parsing html from which i would like to get the data

```
<td id="Company" style="border-bottom-width: 0px; padding-left: 5px">
<strong>ABC</strong>
</td>
```

so the data i need is of course "ABC" only, i have tried the following parsing rule but it does not work

```
/<td id=\"Company\" style=\"border-bottom-width: 0px; padding-left: 5px\">
<strong>(.*)<\/strong>
<\/td>/i
```

anyone can help and is familiar with this?

Answer (score 2):

You really should not use regular expressions to parse html. It always ends up in an convoluted tangled mess.

Use a library which has the functionality of tidy like Beautiful Soup, JTidy, nekohtml,.... and walk the DOM tree (or handles the sax events) to get at the contents of the tags.

Regex-es are then beautiful to get the nuggets from the rocks once the HTML/XML parsing is done however.

Comment: hi, but that's the only way i can do it, the other works, just this one won't show up

Comment: Check for difference in whitespace : CR-LF vs just CR, spaces, spaces vs tabs. XML is (mostly) space agnostic, regexes are not. Another point is that many regex implementatations require you to specifically turn on "multiline" matching.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex to get text in STRONG tag nested in cell:

```
/<td\s*id="Company"[^>]*>\s*<strong>(.*?)</strong>\s*</td>/ms
```

Comment: regex is useless where html parsing required because every time structure of document may be change may be <b> inside string it depends who make html

Answer (score 0):

Simple use HtmlAgilityPack

```
HtmlDocumet doc= new HtmlDocument();
doc.loadHtml("<td id="Company" style="border-bottom-width: 0px; padding-left: 5px">
<strong>ABC</strong>
</td>");

HtmlNode node= doc.DocumentNode.selectSingleNode("//strong");

if(node!=null)
     String value= node.innerText;// value have ABC
```

if you have to get html from web use

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
var response= (HttpWebResponse)request.getresponse();

 using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))) // you could change encoding
                    {
                        output = stream.ReadToEnd(); // output now have html in string form
                    }
```

outpul variable contains html in string foam you can use this string to pass to doc.loadHtml(output);

if want more info google 'htmlagilitypack' and 'HtmlDocument' :)